# How to assign default value in a parameter?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, oledb, default-value

I have the codes below that will display data from access database into textboxes of another form.

```
item items = new item();
Add_Order addorder = new Add_Order();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from tblItems WHERE ItemName = @Item", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", items.ItemName1);
cmd.Connection = connection;
connection.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", addorder.tbItemID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", addorder.tbName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemPrice", addorder.tbPrice.Text);
OleDbDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (read.Read())
{
    addorder.tbItemID.Text = read[0].ToString();
    addorder.tbName.Text = read[1].ToString();
    addorder.tbPrice.Text = read[2].ToString();
}
addorder.ShowDialog();
connection.Close();
```

the error says that

> Parameter @Item has no default value

But I already assigned the value of `@Item` in this line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", items.ItemName1);
```

Comment: is there any values for items.ItemName1?

Comment: As far as I know, you don't need the '@' sign when assigning parameter

Comment: @ling.s - items there is a class. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = items.ItemName1;
```

And why are you using this again after `ExecuteNonQuery()`..?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", addorder.tbItemID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemName", addorder.tbName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemPrice", addorder.tbPrice.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found some mistakes, you are retrieving some items. Then, Why you are using ExecuteNonquery() and some other parameters. Simply try this

```
cmd.Connection = connection;
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from tblItems WHERE ItemName = @Item", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", items.ItemName1);

OleDbDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (read.Read())
{
addorder.tbItemID.Text = read[0].ToString();
addorder.tbName.Text = read[1].ToString();
addorder.tbPrice.Text = read[2].ToString();
}
connection.Close();
```

Make sure that items.ItemName1 has a valid entry. You can verify this by simply passing some values manually as

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", "some text");
```

Comment: Good code, the only thing I'd change is instead of passing index value, I would pass column names.... God forbid the table gets reorganized and that code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("item", OleDbType.VarChar, 32,  "Item").Value = items.ItemName1;
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the point is to construct Parameter()